# Doxygen: Files having hash ( # ) in name

Tags: filenames, doxygen

I have a problem with generating documentation for files with # in their names. I.e. :

```
Filename ab#cd.h starts with line:
/** @file ab#cd.h some description */
```

This description is missing in generated Doxygen HTML.
Also all links were wrong but they have been fixed by additional script which exchange # into %23. I'm thinking of another script for renaming file name before and after generation but maybe there is a possibility to deal with the issue in some other way?

Why # char influence Doxygen documentation generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashes in filenames are a recipe for problems, but in your example you could simply write

```
/** @file
 *  some description
 */
```

No need for the file name, and the description should be put on the next line.

Comment: Thank You. Your solution fixes my problem with hashes (for now :P). "Hashes in filenames are a recipe for problems" - totally agree but it could be worse. They might use hashes and spaces...

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen uses # for links. I believe you can escape a # with a \, but I'm not positive.